# Calculating ComboBox DropDownWidth in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, drop-down-menu

In my application a ComboBox gets resized, so that it is smaller.  How do I re-calculate the DropDownWidth property?  I know how to set it, but I'd prefer to calculate the proper width because its contents changes.  Preferabley, I was thinking of something along these lines:

```
int iMaxLen = 0;
foreach item in comboBoxList
{
   iMaxLen = (item.Length > iMaxLen) ? item.Length : iMaxLen;
}
comboBoxList.DropDownWidth = iMaxLen;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Adjust combo box drop down list width to longest string width**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ComboBoxAutoWidth.aspx