# How to make the ComboBox drop down list resize itself to fit the largest item?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

I've got a `DataGridView` with a `ComboBox` in it that might contain some pretty large strings. Is there a way to have the drop down list expand itself or at least wordwrap the strings so the user can see the whole string without me having to resize the `ComboBox` column width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve this, works great...

```
public class ImprovedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public ImprovedComboBox()
    {



    }
    public object DataSource
    {
        get { return base.DataSource; }
        set { base.DataSource = value; DetermineDropDownWidth(); }

    }
    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get { return base.DisplayMember; }
        set { base.DisplayMember = value; DetermineDropDownWidth(); }

    }
    public string ValueMember
    {
        get { return base.ValueMember; }
        set { base.ValueMember = value; DetermineDropDownWidth(); }

    }
    private void DetermineDropDownWidth()
    {

        int widestStringInPixels = 0;
        foreach (Object o in Items)
        {
            string toCheck;
            PropertyInfo pinfo;
            Type objectType = o.GetType();
            if (this.DisplayMember.CompareTo("") == 0)
            {
                toCheck = o.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                pinfo = objectType.GetProperty(this.DisplayMember);
                toCheck = pinfo.GetValue(o, null).ToString();

            }
            if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(toCheck, this.Font).Width > widestStringInPixels)
                widestStringInPixels = TextRenderer.MeasureText(toCheck, this.Font).Width;
        }
        this.DropDownWidth = widestStringInPixels + 15;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose to modify DropDownWidth property in the DropDown event.

Comment: It might be a better idea to subscribe for `DataSourceChanged`, `ValueMemberChanged` and `DisplayMemberChanged` events instead of property hiding.

Comment: Since it's a class override, the cleanest way is to just add an override for `OnDropDown` to add the call there before executing `base.OnDropDown(e)`. And btw, for that final `if >` check, just store that width in a variable instead of calling that calculation twice.

Comment: By the way, the "+15" thing to allow for the scrollbar can be enhanced by actually checking if it's needed, and by fetching the actual real scrollbar width: `if (this.Items.Count * this.ItemHeight > this.DropDownHeight) widestStringInPixels += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;`

Answer (score 12):

This is very elegant solution:

```
private void AdjustWidthComboBox_DropDown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    int width = senderComboBox.DropDownWidth;
    Graphics g = senderComboBox.CreateGraphics();
    Font font = senderComboBox.Font;
    int vertScrollBarWidth = 
        (senderComboBox.Items.Count>senderComboBox.MaxDropDownItems)
        ?SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth:0;

    int newWidth;
    foreach (string s in senderComboBox.Items)
    {
        newWidth = (int) g.MeasureString(s, font).Width 
            + vertScrollBarWidth;
        if (width < newWidth )
        {
            width = newWidth;
        }
    }
    senderComboBox.DropDownWidth = width;
}
```

**Adjust combo box drop down list width to longest string width** http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ComboBoxAutoWidth.aspx

Source:
[Calculating ComboBox DropDownWidth in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898184/calculating-combobox-dropdownwidth-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score -3):

Not that I know of, although some browsers are smart enough to expand the width of the drop down menu beyond that of the box if it is needed. I know Firefox and Chrome can do it if you're able to control your user base a little.

If you really are desperate how about a flash based combo box posting data back to html?

Comment: Was looking for a winforms answer. I should add winforms to the question. Sorry for the confusion.